# How to target SCOM 2007 R2 monitor to monitor only one server

Tags: windows, monitoring, scom

This might be basic, but hopefully someone can help me:

We have a well-working SCOM 2007 R2 implementation monitoring our Microsoft infrastructure. Now, on one of these servers there's an event (logged to the eventlog) that I need to be alerted on.

I have created a group and put this one windows server in it. Then, I created a monitor with simple event detection, entered the event id and used the group name as "monitor target".
This doesnt work - the monitor doesn't show up in health explorer at all.

However, If I create the monitor with "Windows computers" as target it works, but that means I'll have to disable the monitor, and then enable it for the group, which is cumbersome and slightly illogical to me.

Is this by design, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trondh,

i believe it is by design, yes.

a great resource for OpsMgr can be found at http://www.systemcentercentral.com/